# Why do Powerline colors dim and stay dimmed when switching buffers?

Tags: buffers, plugin-powerline

When I first open vim, the Powerline plugin works as expected:
[image: Normal Powerline]

If I then switch to another buffer, the coloring of powerline's status bar is gone and it remains that way even if switching back to the original buffer:
[image: AfterBufferSwitch]

Any idea why this is happening? How do I fix it?